# GDB - can I find large data elements in memory

Tags: c, gdb

I have a program which has a significant number of statically defined variables.  If I start it up in GDB, with a break point in main, and then run pmap, I see there is about 100MB of data already allocated:

```
08838000 107576K rw---    [ anon ]
```

I've already found a pile of functions that have enormous statically defined arrays (e.g. 200,000 ints) and got rid of them as I've found them.

Is there any way to find out what the largest items are on the heap / data segments?  Either in GDB or through any other means?

Comment: You can get symbol (object) sizes through objdump and nm output. Debug information needed, I think.

Comment: Awesome!  Fancy writing it as an answer :)  nm --size-sort does exactly what I was looking for (and found a 20 MB array of 2,500,000 ints in some test code that will never be used on most systems!)

Comment: This sounds like a bit of code suffering from a lack of attention :)

Comment: Yep, I thought I was looking for stuff in the app-specific bits, but it turns out most of the biggest culprits are part of the core code that I'm in charge of!  Makes it easier for me to fix at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information can be found by using the object code inspection utilities like nm(1):

```
nm --size-sort <object-file.o>
```

Also, objdump can give additional insights for the completely linked program, given enough debug information.

The utilities are often target platform specific, so when cross-compiling care must be taken to use the correct program (i.e. something like `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm` instead of just `nm`).

Comment: The C++ mangled names can be postprocessed in their more (or less, if you have one template to many) readable form with `c++filt`.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Right. Sometimes it doesn't work (I failed to find out why), but should be tried anyway.