# When is static data (.bss) allocated?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I have been looking into reducing the memory footprint of an application.  Following on from a previous question: [GDB - can I find large data elements in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613713/gdb-can-i-find-large-data-elements-in-memory) I have found and removed most of the biggest culprits.

`nm --size-sort` was invaluable finding the large items from the .bss section of the executables.

The memory footprint as viewed in pmap has dropped very substantially.  But while continuing this work on another system (Ubuntu Pangolin, gcc 4.6.3), I have noticed the memory footprint of running processes is perfectly reasonable, and certainly much smaller than the .bss size.

Running the code through the debugger, it looks like the biggest symbols from the .bss section are not really being allocated until the data is accessed (i.e. I can set an array 
element from one of the big symbols, and the memory footprint grows by 16MB).

The .bss section is just zero-initialised, so it is easy to imagine an implementation assigning virtual address space to it, but not actually assigning any real memory until it is used.

Is this a real difference in behaviour, or a difference in reporting between systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux zero-initialized pages are all mapped to the same "zeroed" physical page in memory. Using a copy-on-write method, a page is copied and re-mapped to a new page when you write to the memory of that page, which in turn causes the memory footprint of the application to grow. Sounds like this is what is happening, as you suspect. This would hold for all Linux distros.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable.  I don't suppose you know how long this has been true for?  I see that the system showing the enormous memory footprint is 2007-era (SLES 10.1).

Comment: Linux has handled zero pages like this for a long time. The shared ZERO_PAGE is present in Linux 2.4, as is the copy-on-write support in the page fault handler.